# If using AF_IB, should I call rdma_resolve_addr()?

Tags: rdma

Some code call rdma_resolve_addr() in using AF_INET(ip). And I knew that this function can translate ip to rdma addr. But if using AF_IB, should I call rdma_resolve_addr()?

I found that there is an function called rdma_resolve_addr2() in rdma_resolve_addr(). But it seems not the key.